# Conversion of std:string to char*

Tags: c++, c++builder, rad-studio

I'm trying to convert a `result` string that I get by doing some data manipulation, eg:

```
std::string result = std::string(/* num_max */, '0').append(myDataModule->getId().c_str());
```

I'm getting an id from `getId()` (which returns an `AnsiString`) on my `TDataModule`, converting that to a `std::string` using `AnsiString::c_str()`, and appending that with zeros on the left (spaces that will remain) to my `result` string.

I need to use the value of `result` in a function that receives a `char *`:

```c
void receiver(char * data, int num){
  ... <- A lot of code here

  if( data != NULL )
  {
    strcpy( rdData, data); <-- rdData is an char *
    ...
  }
}
```

Basically, in this function it will copy `data` to `rdData` and do some verifications.

When I run the code, an error appears when I call this function:

> candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string') to 'char *' for 1st argument

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: If the result of `myDataModule->getId()` is a `std::string`, then I can't repro this: https://ideone.com/C9w12k

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::string::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)?

Comment: What is the return type of `getId()` ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post, I edited the question, added the return type of `getId()`.

Comment: Are you sure that the posted line is the one that generates the error? To me it sounds that the error comes when you use `result` in the function call later on.

Comment: See here: https://ideone.com/9IHnhU This is the same error but it's from another line...

Comment: "*I'm doing an Android app*" - which version of C++Builder are you using? Not all versions support using `AnsiString` on Android.

Comment: @GA1I You still haven't shown **how you call** `receiver`. Don't you get a line number together with the error messages so that you can tell exactly which line causes the error?

Comment: Yes... But it doesn't need, look: I just wanted to convert. Like an optional for `append()`. Using `StringOfChar()` and letting the var in `AnsiString` resolved my problem. Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I run the code, an error appears when I call this function:
>
> > candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string') to 'char *' for 1st argument

You did not show the actual code that is trying to pass the `std::string` to the `receiver()` function, but the error message is very clear.  You simply cannot assign a `std::string` *directly* to a non-const `char*`, which is exactly what the compiler is complaining about.

However, you can get a `const char*` from a `std::string` using its `c_str()` method, and then you can `const_cast` that to a `char*` (as long as the function does not try to modify the `char` data), eg:

```cpp
std::string result = ...;
receiver(const_cast<char*>(result.c_str()), static_cast<int>(result.size()));
```

Or, you can simply use `&result[0]` instead (which is guaranteed in C++11 and later to be contiguous and null-terminated), or you can use `result.data()` in C++17 and later, eg:

```cpp
std::string result = ...;
receiver(&result[0]/*result.data()*/, static_cast<int>(result.size()));
```

Or, you could simply change `result` from `std::string` to `AnsiString`, as its `c_str()` method returns a non-const `char*`, eg:

```cpp
AnsiString result = AnsiString::StringOfChar('0', 8) + myDataModule->getId();
receiver(result.c_str(), result.Length());
```

Either way, if `receiver()` only needs to read from `data` and not modify its content, then it *should* be changed to take `data` as a `const char*` instead (especially since that is what [`strcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) expects anyway), eg:

```cpp
void receiver(const char * data, int num)
```

Then you can use `result.c_str()` as-is, no trickery, whether `result` is an `AnsiString` or a `std::string`.

Comment: Have to ask... How could you post an answer to a closed question?

Comment: The timeline says it was. Closed 17 min ago. Answer posted 12 min ago.

Comment: @4386427 the system must really like me ;-) Oh wait, it's not that, see [This answer was posted *after* the question was closed, how is that possible?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/) and [How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/)

Comment: Strange - must be a bug. Anyway - pretty sure your answer is correct but can't really know as OP just disappeared and stopped answering comments :-(

Comment: Wow - I didn't know about that "grace period" and it's around 4 hours. So it's not a bug - just "strange design" :-)

Comment: Yeah!!! That's it, I use `StringOfChar()` and it converted to me. Thank you so much (and again) Remy!!!

Comment: PS: How can I reopen this question? I've already edited (I'm not an StackOverFlow expert hehe).

Comment: @GA1I "*How can I reopen this question?*" - YOU can't, 3 OTHER PEOPLE have to submit a vote to reopen it (I already submitted my vote). If it receives 3 reopen votes, it will be reopened automatically. "*I'm not an StackOverFlow expert*" - then I suggest you read the [help]

Comment: All right, thx.